# Show that if $x = y + z$ , and $d$ is a divisor of any two of the integers $x$, $y$, and $z$, it is also a divisor of the third.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that if $x = y + z$ , and $d$ is a divisor of any two of the integers $x$, $y$, and $z$, it is also a divisor of the third.

How should I approach this problem and using what method to solve this problem? It seems so logical, but I can't seem to show how.

Comment: Note, $d$ is a divisor of $x$ if and only if it is also a divisor of $-x$.  It may be easier to work then with the statement:  If $0=-x+y+z$ and $d$ is a divisor of any two of the integers $-x, y, z$ then it is also a divisor of the third.  Suppose without loss of generality that it is a divisor of $-x$ and $y$.  Then $-x$ can be written as... and $y$ can be written as...  Moving them to one side and combining like terms we have $z$ can be written as...

Comment: If and only if $d$ is a divisor of $x$, you can write $x$ as $d\times x'$, where $x'$ is an integer.

Comment: You might be interested in learning more about posting mathematical expressions, possible here with [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Break it down into three cases.

1. Assume $d$ is a divisor of $x$ and $y$, show that it divides $z$.
2. Assume $d$ is a divisor of $x$ and $z$, show that it divides $y$.
3. Assume $d$ is a divisor of $y$ and $z$, show that it divides $x$.

The third one: Since $d$ divides $y$ and $z$ we can write $y=dm$ and $z=dn$ for some integers $m$ and $n$. Now $x=y+z=dm+dn=d(m+n)$ which means that $d$ is a divisor of $x$.

The other two are very similar.

Comment: Funny, I actually had that in mind. The problem was showing it.

Comment: If you figure out any one of these, then the other two are very similar.

Comment: Of course. The problem of one can solve the problem for all.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to do the third one. The others are similar.

Comment: I was so close to doing what you were doing except I never set my own "quotients" into another variable. That's why I was confused. Thanks so much.